# How to resize an Image widget in CardService?

Tags: google-apps-script, image-manipulation

In a Gmail Add-On, you can add an image to show in a Card.

However, it seems the image is sized to be 100% of the width of the Card.

```
section.addWidget(CardService.newImage()
                      .setAltText("Alt image text")
                      .setImageUrl("https://source/image.png"));
```

Is there a way to specify the size of the image so it is not expanded to the full width of the card?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, providing the width/height of the image is provided in gmail add-on.